# Can you multiply a matrix out of another one?

Tags: matrices

This is actually from a computer graphics problem.

I calculate a transformation matrix by multiplying a few other ones.

```
Matrix final = moveToZero * scale * translation * master;
```

Now later, I would like to get the master matrix out of the final matrix again without having access to all of them.

So I am looking for  a function like this:

```
Matrix base = RemoveMatrix(final, master); // should be like moveToZero * scale * translation
```

I would like to know if this is even mathematically possible.

Comment: Are you trying to recover moveToZero * scale * translation from final?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C,D,E$ be matrices.  If $A = BCDE$, then $E=D^{-1}C^{-1}B^{-1}A$, (notice the order of the matrices) assuming $B$, $C$, and $D$ are invertible.  If they're not invertible you probably can't get $E$ out as multiplication by noninvertible matrices is generally a lossy process (to borrow a data compression term).